# How to properly display an HTML page after PHP script?

Tags: php, html, echo

somehow I couldn't find an answer to the following problem when searching the web.

I'm not familiar with PHP and am trying to get the below PHP code, which I put right at the beginning of the file, to display the HTML page that follows, instead of "Welcome.".

Many thanks for your time!

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    die('<script>window.location = "https://test.com/login.php"</script>');
}
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
echo "Welcome.";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="De">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
...
```

Comment: Looks like you're attempting a re-direct based on some PHP session variables - you may want to consider using [`header()`](http://php.net/header) for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Do you mean I should use "header("Location: http://www.example.com/");" instead of "echo "Welcome."? The problem is that those couple of lines of PHP are already on the page I'd like to show, the HTML code being right below. Mmh.

Comment: @waterloomatt Currently, the page (example: home.php) displays the message "Welcome.", but I'd like the page home.php to display the html code that is below the echo command. Might be a stupid question, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    die('<script>window.location = "https://test.com/login.php"</script>');
}
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

echo <<<HTML

--> HTML section/code <--

HTML;
```

?>